# Eclipse 3.5+ - Annotation processor: Generated classes cannot be imported

Tags: java, eclipse, import, annotation-processing

I am using a 3rd party annotation processor for generating meta-data code (.java files) from the annotated classes in my project.
I have successfully configured the processor through Eclipse (Properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing) and the code generation works fine (code is automatically created and generated). Also, Eclipse successfully auto-completes the generated classes and their fields, without any errors. Let's say that I have a class "some.package.Foo" and that the generated meta-data class is "some.package.Foo_". By the help of auto-completion, I can get the following code in the Eclipse editor, without any errors:

```
import some.package.Foo_;
...
public class Test {
  void test() {
    Foo_.someField = null; // try to access a field from the generated class Foo_
  }
}
```

However, as soon as I actually build the project (or just save the file since Build automatically is enabled), I get the error which tells that "some.package.Foo_" cannot be resolved.
It seems like Eclipse is generating and compiling the some.package.Foo_ at the same time, or more likely.

I found two temporary solutions (which are practically hindering the use of the annotation processor in the first place):

1. Before each build of that generated classes, right click on every generated file go to Properties and uncheck the "Derived" tick. After that, I do the cleanup of the project and the imports are fine - there are no more errors. However, if I do the cleanup one more time, the errors again show up, because the generation of the files causes the "Derived" tick to be checked again (automatically). So this is really annoying and time-consuming.
2. I also uncheck the "Derived" tick
       from all those files, and this time
       I uncheck the "Derived" tick from
       the source folder and packages which
       contain those files. Then I disable
       the annotation processor, and then
       do the cleanup. There are no more
       import errors, even if I do another
       cleanup, but there is no benefit of
       using the annotation processor,
       because if I was to change something
       which would update the model, I need
       to turn the annotation processor
       back on, and repeat this tedious
       procedure to turn it off, after it
       has generated the new version of
       those files.

Is this a bug in Eclipse? If yes, is there a better workaround or quick-fix than the two I have stated above? If not, what should I try to solve the problem?

I also tried rearranging the order of the libraries on the build path and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are generating sources in the last processor round. This is not recommended way and leads exactly to the problem that you had.
Explanation is here: http://code.google.com/p/acris/wiki/CodeGenerationPlatform_Pitfall_Rounds

So the my advise is to generate sources in regular processing rounds and final round should be used just for notification that processing is over or something like that.

Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem, and the only thing I've found is that it's the *imports* specifically that don't work, but the references in the class itself do work. The workaround I've used is to use the FQCN in all cases where the generated class is needed (except when the generated class is in the same package, since then the import is obviously not needed).

So to use your example, I'd do:

```
public class Test {
  void test() {
    some.package.Foo_.someField = null; // try to access a field from the generated class Foo_
  }
}
```

My only guess then is that the eclipse compiler is processing the imports before doing the annotation processing, which imho must be a bug in eclipse.

I know this question is over a year old, so I'd be interested to know if you've found any other way to fix it.

Comment: We have exactly the same problem with [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org), occurs randomly when opening Eclipse. Didn't find any clear solution yet, though changing the annotation processing folder name ".apt_generated" triggers a build that sometimes solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We were experiencing a similar problem and apparently just solved it, so thought of sharing it at SO, in case it helps someone.

**We are using:**

- Eclipse Indigo (Build id: 20120216-1857)
- m2e Connector for maven
- openJPA for static metamodel class generation

**Our problem:**

Say, we have a package named com.abc.xyz and an entity class in there named OurEntity. When we build the projects (JPA, EJB, EAR etc. all together with an mvn clean at the beginning) the metamodel classes get generated. And also get appropriately packaged within the PU jar. But when we try to import the generated metamodel class com.abc.xyz.OurEntity_, Eclipse cannot resolve it. OP apparently got past this point:-). Maven build failed, saying it could not resolve that class. Not much help from google except for a few bug reports such as this one: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350378

That bug report said importing the whole package as opposed to the single class helped. So, tried that, but with no benefit. It also said (and so did David Heitzman) that using the fully qualified class name worked for them. That did not work either.

**The solution:**

**Added the PU jar to Eclipse build path** for the project that needed to use the metamodel classes. All of a sudden all the red underlines went away (not a surprise). But the fear was there might be two PUs in the same ear. But maven automagically took care of that.

Answer (score 0):

As this rather old question got some attention without pointing to the very probable eclipse bug the OP was specifically asking for, I'd like to complement the above answers with a pointer to the eclipse bug tracker:

[Cannot resolve import for generated class IF processing annotations with parameters referencing constants](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387956)

The workarounds include

1. doing a wildcard import of the package defining the generated classes (i.e. `import some.package.*;`)
2. using the fully qualified name of your generated class, i.e. referring to `some.package.Foo` in your code and not using an import
3. switch to a newer Eclipse. This specific eclipse bug is resolved with Eclipse version 4.4 (aka Luna).