# How to specify build order in an Android project using AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, android-annotations

I use AndroidAnnotations, and since a couple of days, Eclipse sometimes (not always) fails to compile code that uses classes generated by AndroidAnnotations (pre-compile generated code):

My example is:

My project has `MainActivity`, AndroidAnnotations creates an extended class `MainActivity_` under .apt_generated.

Elsewhere in the `DetailActivity`, my code has a reference to MainActivity_:

[image]

My solution so far was to remove the code, compile, then add the code back. However, this is far from elegant. It also is quite annoying and time-consuming.

Am I missing some setting?

Does the order in the "Order and Export" page have any influence? I've tried to move the .apt_generated directory up and down, with no positive effect.

I was thinking that this is the same concept used by Android's resource class R. I never had any issues with code that use resources failing to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments above from [piwai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703646/piwai) the anwser is:

[Eclipse 3.5+ - Annotation processor: Generated classes cannot be imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580564/eclipse-3-5-annotation-processor-generated-classes-cannot-be-imported/7689369#7689369)

Answer (score 1):

When does that happen?

- When you open Eclipse?
- When you open a project previously closed?
- When you do a **project > clean**?

This problem looks like a bug in Eclipse. It looks like sometimes it compiles a class, then run the annotation processor, then doesn't update / recompile the classes that had missing symbols.

A simple tricks that seems to do the job: go to the properties of the project, change the name of the annotation processing folder from **.apt_generated** to something else (and then back to **.apt_generated**), and accept the rebuild. This seems to trigger a build in the right order, and reset everything right.

Note that AndroidAnnotations uses annotation processing, which is a standard java 6 concept. It's different from the Android R class, which isn't linked to any java standard.

Does that help?

Comment: It happens when I start Eclipse (I think it happened during a session as well, but not 100% sure). After I do the trick I described, it goes away.

Unfortunately, changing the name of annotation processing folder did not help. Any other idea's to try? I run eclipse 3.7.2.

Comment: Damn. It should. As I'm always switching branches in Git, I usually do something like "refresh > clean" and then change folder name if needed. Maybe you could also try to disable annotation processing, do a clean, then reenable it ? Let's try to find the right sequence. This really is an Eclipse bug, should happen on other annotation processors...

Comment: Look at this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7689369/703646 => Could you try to use the fully qualified name of MyActivity_ in your class (com.company.MyActivity_) and see if it still happens?

Comment: I also realized we were handling rounds in a bad way, see [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/231). Does the latest [2.6-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/androidannotations/androidannotations/2.6-SNAPSHOT/) still have the problem ?

Comment: FQN solved the problem. I restarted Eclipse a couple of times, and the symptom is not there. I will the snapshot (without FQN, i.e. import) tomorrow, and report back. This solved a big annoyance.

Comment: using the latest androidannotations-2.6-20120614.102335-42.zip alone (without using the FQN) DID NOT solve the problem. So, I guess as http://stackoverflow.com/a/7689369/95976 suggested, the might be a bug in eclipse in the order of processing things.

Comment: sadly this problem is still occurring in v3.0